# Camera sound in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am trying to scan bar code using windows phone 8.1. This works properly but the camera makes sound when it is scanning. I would like to mute the camera sound. How to disable camera capture sound in windows phone 8.1 pro grammatically?

Comment: Maybe you can't. In my country, devices are required by law to emit a sound while taking a picture or a movie, to avoid people capturing the image of others without them knowing about it.

Comment: In our country, South Korea, also force commercial phones to make shutter sound at almost maximum volume.

Comment: For example, in amazon app, while scanning barcode, there wont be any sound from camera. So  there should be some way to control camera sound from backend code. Does any one know how to control the sound using C#?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to mute the camera sound when taking a picture. However, there is no sound when using the camera in video mode. So you can start the camera in video mode (no recording needed) and analyze the frames of the video the same way you analyze the picture taken.